# mysql sort high score such that player placedin 8th position to show complete 15 results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm making a rank based game using unity. But I got stuck in the query for the best match please help me out.

**The SQL Query:**

```
SELECT name, high_score, @rn:=@rn+1 as row_num
FROM   score, (select @rn:=0) as r 
ORDER BY high_score DESC
```

**The SQL Table:**

```
row_number | score | firstname 
-------------------------------
    1      |  210  | Bill      
    2      |  431  | Linus     
    3      |  352  | Rasmus    
    4      |  173  | Steve     
    5      |  294  | Ross      
    6      |  411  | Henry     
    7      |  313  | Jagannath    
    8      |  115  | Samit    
    9      |  217  | Vishal      
    10     |  419  | Tanuj     
    11     |  321  | Harshad    
    12     |  123  | Parag    
    13     |  225  | Aman      
    14     |  427  | Amar     
    15     |  329  | Madhur    
    16     |  131  | Sachin
```

I want the result like below:
For name'Ross' i.e on 7th position between high and low scores.

Note: The database has thousands of users but result must be 15.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CroRd.png

Comment: order by score won't help? you will find Ross on 7th position then

Comment: If you only want 15 users in your query result (instead of the thousand users), then try to append `LIMIT 15;` at the end of your query.

Comment: I guess your query is correct just order your result in desc mode on score and add rownum <= 15 in your where clause

Comment: data base might have different values and Ross is just an example it might be Bill,Linus etc

Comment: Thanks Marco,Sacha and abki bar Modi..If I query best match for 'Parag' it should rank all players according to scores and it should display 7 above and 7 below ,if he is topper then rest 14 will positioned below him

Comment: I will post some result screen shortly

Comment: There is no name (or high_score) column in your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following. Note, I've used 11 instead of 15 in this example (just because it was easier to test against the sample data set). Also, my core algorithm is slower than yours and it doesn't account for ties - so you may want to switch it for something like yours, which is faster, and does!

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS score;

CREATE TABLE score
(score INT NOT NULL,firstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO score VALUES
(210  ,'Bill'),
(431  ,'Linus'),
(352  ,'Rasmus'),
(173  ,'Steve'),
(294  ,'Ross'),
(411  ,'Henry'),
(313  ,'Jagannath'),
(115  ,'Samit'),
(217  ,'Vishal'),
(419  ,'Tanuj'),
(321  ,'Harshad'),
(123  ,'Parag'),
(225  ,'Aman'),
(427  ,'Amar'),
(329  ,'Madhur'),
(131  ,'Sachin');

    SELECT score,firstname,rank
      FROM 
         ( SELECT b.*
             FROM
                ( SELECT x.*
                       , COUNT(*) rank
                    FROM score x
                    JOIN score y
                      ON y.score >= x.score
                   GROUP
                      BY firstname,score
                ) a
             JOIN
                ( SELECT x.*
                       , COUNT(*) rank
                    FROM score x
                    JOIN score y
                      ON y.score >= x.score
                   GROUP
                      BY firstname,score
                ) b
            WHERE a.firstname = 'Ross'
              AND ABS(b.rank-a.rank) <=15 
            ORDER
               BY ABS(b.rank-a.rank) LIMIT 11
         ) n
     ORDER 
        BY rank;

    +-------+-----------+------+
    | score | firstname | rank |
    +-------+-----------+------+
    |   411 | Henry     |    4 |
    |   352 | Rasmus    |    5 |
    |   329 | Madhur    |    6 |
    |   321 | Harshad   |    7 |
    |   313 | Jagannath |    8 |
    |   294 | Ross      |    9 |
    |   225 | Aman      |   10 |
    |   217 | Vishal    |   11 |
    |   210 | Bill      |   12 |
    |   173 | Steve     |   13 |
    |   131 | Sachin    |   14 |
    +-------+-----------+------+
```